# How to show the a custom taxonomy term on single post metadata

Tags: custom-taxonomy, meta-query, taxonomy-meta

I have a custom taxonomy called "Sources" (using Custom Post Type UI), where the sources are the names of publications where articles were originally published. Each post is an article, with a source selected. What I need to do is to show the source in the metadata under the post title. I'm using the Avada theme. Currently the title area of a post looks like this:

**Article Title**

By Author Name | Month, Year

What I want is this:

**Article Title**

Author Name, *Source*, Month, Year

Here's an example post I'm working with in my dev environment:

http://dev.universaltheosophy.com/articles/the-logos-and-meditation/

I'd love to be able to do this with add_action in my child theme's functions.php, and hook it before the date or after the author name. But I'm not sure how to do that.

All I see in the theme's single post file file is:

```
<?php if ( 'below' === Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_post_title' ) ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'below_title' === Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_post_meta_position' ) ) : ?>
                <div class="fusion-post-title-meta-wrap">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $title_size = ( false === avada_is_page_title_bar_enabled( $post->ID ) ? '1' : '2' ); ?>
            <?php echo avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', $title_size ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput ?>
            <?php if ( 'below_title' === Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_post_meta_position' ) ) : ?>
                <?php echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'single' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

And I see in the theme's files:

```
            // Render author meta data.
        if ( $settings['post_meta_author'] ) {
            ob_start();
            the_author_posts_link();
            $author_post_link = ob_get_clean();

            // Check if rich snippets are enabled.
            if ( fusion_library()->get_option( 'disable_date_rich_snippet_pages' ) && fusion_library()->get_option( 'disable_rich_snippet_author' ) ) {
                /* translators: The author. */
                $metadata .= sprintf( esc_html__( 'By %s', 'Avada' ), '<span class="vcard"><span class="fn">' . $author_post_link . '</span></span>' );
            } else {
                /* translators: The author. */
                $metadata .= sprintf( esc_html__( 'By %s', 'Avada' ), '<span>' . $author_post_link . '</span>' );
            }
            $metadata .= '<span class="fusion-inline-sep">|</span>';
        } else { // If author meta data won't be visible, render just the invisible author rich snippet.
            $author .= fusion_render_rich_snippets_for_pages( false, true, false );
        }

        // Render the updated meta data or at least the rich snippet if enabled.
        if ( $settings['post_meta_date'] ) {
            $metadata .= fusion_render_rich_snippets_for_pages( false, false, true );

            $formatted_date = get_the_time( fusion_library()->get_option( 'date_format' ) );
            $date_markup    = '<span>' . $formatted_date . '</span><span class="fusion-inline-sep">|</span>';
            $metadata      .= apply_filters( 'fusion_post_metadata_date', $date_markup, $formatted_date );
        } else {
            $date .= fusion_render_rich_snippets_for_pages( false, false, true );
        }
```

Other than this, I'm not sure what other info I need. Any help will be much appreciated! Keep in mind I'm very amateur at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this out with the help of several tutorials. Here's the code I'm using now:

```
function jwf_single_post_meta() {

// CATEGORY
$categories = get_the_category();
$catoutput = '';
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $catoutput .= '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>';
    }
}

// AUTHOR
$author = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' );
$authorlink = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );

// SOURCE   
$sources = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'source' );
if ( ! empty( $sources ) && ! is_wp_error( $sources ) ){
foreach ( $sources as $source ) {
    $sourcename = $source->name;    
    }
$sourcelink = get_term_link( $source );
$sep = __( ',' );
}   

// DATE
$original_date = get_the_time( 'F, Y' );
// $modified_date = get_the_modified_time( 'F, Y' );
// [Last Modified: $modified_date]</span>

echo "<span class='jwf-single-meta'>$catoutput by <a href='$authorlink'>$author</a>, <em><a href='$sourcelink'>$sourcename</a></em>$sep $original_date";

}
```

End result is: Category by Author, *Source*, Month, Year

Examples: Article by Joe Smith, *Magazine Name*, October, 1975

Translation by Some Guy, *Series Name*, January, 2010

I've tested two methods for inserting this, both include putting the above code in my child theme's functions.php file. Option one is to use add_filter to override the theme's single post meta function `add_filter( 'the_author_posts_link', 'jwf_single_post_meta' );`. Option two is to override the theme's single.php and insert the function there `<?php echo jwf_single_post_meta(); ?>`. Option 2 is what I'm going with for now.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `the_author_posts_link` filter to do this:

```
add_filter( 'the_author_posts_link', functoin ($link) {

  global $post_id;

  // get "source" tax terms
  $sources = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'source' );

  // build html
  $html = '';

  foreach ($sources as $source) {
    $html += '<a href="'. get_term_link($source) .'">'. $source->name .'</a>';
  }

  // pre-pend html to author link

  $link = $link . $html;

  return $link;
});
```

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_posts_link/

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be something not quite right though. All I'm getting is a 0 instead of the source name, i.e. Author Name**0** | Month, Year. Not sure what that means.